# Reduce Firestore write operations by using offline cache

Tags: android, database, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I use Firebase Firestore for my unity game(android).

It's mainly used to save the players progress, since I want to keep the progress in case of a crash or if the OS kills the app in the background, I need to do constant saves, which get expensive.

In the ideal case, I would like to do the constant saving to the offline cache, and just every x hours, sync/overwrite it on the online DB.
The functionality "disable network" sounded perfect, however, all the writes I did while offline, get executed in a queue and counted as if there where done online, even if I set the Mergeoptions to overwrite.

Is there any way to achive this?

Ofc I could save locally to my own jsons and only using Firestore as a backup, but running 2 save systems is a mess and the offline functionality was the prime reason why I chose Firestore in the first place.

As a server/DB noob, I would appreciate any suggestions in that area :)

edit: chossing Source.Cached in SetAsync, like in GetSnapShot, or deleting the write operation queue manually would solve my issue, but I have not found any way to do so.